# Hadoop ClassCastException for default value of InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having a issue getting started with my first map-reduce code on Hadoop. I copied the following code from "Hadoop: The definitive guide" but I'm not able to run it on my single node Hadoop installation.

My Code snippet:

Main:

```
Job job = new Job(); 
job.setJarByClass(MaxTemperature.class);
job.setJobName("Max temperature");

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Mapper:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
```

Reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
Context context)
```

Implementations of map and reduce function are also picked from the book only. But when I try to execute this code, this is the error I get:

```
INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304021022_0016_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
    java.lang.ClassCastException: interface javax.xml.soap.Text
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3027)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.<init>(MapTask.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:674)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Answers to similar questions in the past ([Hadoop type mismatch in key from map expected value Text received value LongWritable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319727/hadoop-type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-expected-value-text-received-value-longwrit)) helped me to figure out that InputFormatClass  should match the input to the map function. So I also tried  using  job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);   in my main method, but it also did not solve the issue. What could be the issue here?

Here is the implementation of the Mapper class

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MaxTemperatureMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>     {

private static final int MISSING = 9999;

@Override
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  String line = value.toString();
  String year = line.substring(15, 19);

  int airTemperature;
  if (line.charAt(45) == '+') { // parseInt doesn't like leading plus signs
    airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(46, 50));
  } else {
    airTemperature = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(45, 50));
  }
  String quality = line.substring(50, 51);
  if (airTemperature != MISSING && quality.matches("[01459]")) {
    context.write(new Text(year), new IntWritable(airTemperature));
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You auto imported the wrong import. Instead of import **org.apache.hadoop.io.Text** you imported **import javax.xml.soap.Text**

You can find a sample wrong import in this [blog](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/wrong-import-statements-in-hadoop.html).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the wrong Text class imported (javax.xml.soap.Text). You want org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Comment: Chris, I've no idea where is  javax.xml.soap.Text  coming from. I'm using org.apache.hadoop.io.Text  and I've not included any other third-party jar in the code.

Comment: You checked the class containing the main() method and checked your your Mapper class?  Looks like the exception was thrown in the mapper.  If you're still looking, just post the entire Mapper class, but focus on the declared type of what you wrote to the context.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was using    javax.xml.soap.Text   in my main method. Overlooked it. Changing it to  org.apache.hadoop.io.Text  solved the problem.